# Move dock show applications from right to left not working

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-dock

I'm using ubuntu 18.04, I tried to move the 'show applications' from right to left in my dock using this command in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-apps-at-top true
```

but when I checked the dock, the show applications icon still appears at the right side

[image]

Comment: Did you try rebooting once? What is the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-apps-at-top` now?

Comment: @pomsky the output is false, yes ive tried to reboot it, but still same

Comment: "false" means the command you ran didn't have any effect, it was supposed to switch it to "true". What is the output of `gsettings writable org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-apps-at-top`?

Comment: @pomsky it shows `true`

Comment: @blue are you using the default `ubuntu-dock` or `dash-to-dock` gnome-shell extension?

Comment: @YuganTej ubuntu-dock

Comment: @blue as per the `writable` output.. it should take the input `true` but as per comments.. it is still false.. I am thinking to run `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`